# mysqldump create empty file in win7 wamp

Tags: php, mysql

Here is my code

```
<?php

$dbuser = "root";
$dbpass = "";
$dbname = "test";


$backupfile = $dbname .time()."-".date("Y-M-D h:i:s");


//$query= "C:\\wamp\\bin\\mysql\\mysql5.5.16\\bin\\mysqldump.exe " ."-u ". $dbuser ." -p ". $dbname.">". $backupfile.".sql";
$query= "C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.16\bin\mysqldump.exe " ."-u ". $dbuser ." -p ". $dbname.">". $backupfile.".sql";
echo $query;
system($query);


?>
```

But i am always getting blank file. I am using wamp server in windows 7. I have tried with double slashes and single slashes but same result. Please help me with this essue.

**N.B-** One things i have not mentioned yet that, when i open this in browser, the empty backup file created, but page loading not stop,its show loading....

Comment: You must change "C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.16\bin\mysqldump.exe" to "C:\\wamp\\bin\\mysql\\mysql5.5.16\\bin\\mysqldump.exe"

Comment: I already mentioned it, and see my code i have make this line as a comment line. Tried both but no luck :(

Comment: the command is asking for password, you must add password as command parameter:   []  $dbuser ." -p$dbpass ". $dbname [...]   (without space between pass flag and password)

Comment: Generally I don't use password in wamp server. I think this is not an issue

Comment: then remove "-p " from command and try it again

Comment: To know the exact problem, please open the apache error_log file, there is a error message on last lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$query= "C:\\wamp\\bin\\mysql\\mysql5.5.16\\bin\\mysqldump.exe --user root test > upload/". time()."_backup.sql";
```

Finally it works. I have use `--user` instead of `-u`, as i don't have any password for wamp server, i removed `--password` field. Now its working fine.

Comment: I read many tutorials but this is the only one that helps me in my XAMPP (windows 7). Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

The command is asking for password, you must remove --password parameter or -p flag if you mysql root user password is blank.